# Trying to use pyinstaller on customtkinter

Tags: python, pyinstaller, customtkinter

I tried to use pyinstaller on customtkinter accord to the official documentation but, it didn't work.

My command (I use Mac OS): pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --add-data "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/customtkinter;customtkinter/" “TROLL.py”

My error message:

```
usage: pyinstaller [-h] [-v] [-D] [-F] [--specpath DIR] [-n NAME] [--add-data <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>] [--add-binary <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>] [-p DIR] [--hidden-import MODULENAME]
                   [--collect-submodules MODULENAME] [--collect-data MODULENAME] [--collect-binaries MODULENAME] [--collect-all MODULENAME] [--copy-metadata PACKAGENAME]
                   [--recursive-copy-metadata PACKAGENAME] [--additional-hooks-dir HOOKSPATH] [--runtime-hook RUNTIME_HOOKS] [--exclude-module EXCLUDES] [--key KEY] [--splash IMAGE_FILE]
                   [-d {all,imports,bootloader,noarchive}] [--python-option PYTHON_OPTION] [-s] [--noupx] [--upx-exclude FILE] [-c] [-w] [-i <FILE.ico or FILE.exe,ID or FILE.icns or Image or "NONE">]
                   [--disable-windowed-traceback] [--version-file FILE] [-m <FILE or XML>] [--no-embed-manifest] [-r RESOURCE] [--uac-admin] [--uac-uiaccess] [--win-private-assemblies]
                   [--win-no-prefer-redirects] [--argv-emulation] [--osx-bundle-identifier BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER] [--target-architecture ARCH] [--codesign-identity IDENTITY] [--osx-entitlements-file FILENAME]
                   [--runtime-tmpdir PATH] [--bootloader-ignore-signals] [--distpath DIR] [--workpath WORKPATH] [-y] [--upx-dir UPX_DIR] [-a] [--clean] [--log-level LEVEL]
                   scriptname [scriptname ...]
pyinstaller: error: argument --add-data: invalid add_data_or_binary value: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/customtkinter;customtkinter/'
```

Why does it do that?

I looked into the documentation and my problem was nowhere to be found.

Comment: Check to confirm if your path is correct, or try and use the full path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by changing the semicolon to a colon for the add-data flag.

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --add-data "<CustomTkinter Location>/customtkinter:customtkinter/"  "main.py"
```

Alternatively, you can manually add the data location in a .spec file.

To generate the spec file

```
pyi-makespec --onedir --windowed "main.py"
```

This will generate a .spec file that you can edit. Include the path to the customtkinter library under the Analysis -> datas section.

```
a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/customtkinter', 'customtkinter/')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(...)
coll = COLLECT(...)
app = BUNDLE(...)
```

Afterward run

```
pyinstaller main.spec
```

Hope it works for you. Also if you encounter permission errors during build try running with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to go for **auto-py-to-exe** instead of **pyinstaller** than. It is much easier to use.

To install it, run: `pip install auto-py-to-exe`
and to start it, enter: `auto-py-to-exe` in your command prompt.

Hope it will work for ya.